# Defining has one relationship with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I still don't get how Laravel relationships work, and I've been trying for hours to define a relationship but I can't manage to do it so I would appreciate some help.

My entities are `Negotiation` and `Order`. An order has many negotiations, which I managed to define properly and the `orders_negotiations` table is being fed properly:

```
class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function negotiations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Negotiation', 'orders_negotiations');
    }

}
```

However, now I'm trying to retrieve the order from the negotiation side. I tried this:

```
class Negotiation extends Eloquent {

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order');
    }

}
```

However when doing this `$negotiation->order->id` I am getting this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

And when I try with `hasOne()` instead I am getting this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.negotiation_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`orders`where`orders`.`negotiation_id`= 1 limit 1)`

What am I doing wrong and how should I do it?

Comment: Is your database populated? Because `$negotiation->order` will be null if there are no orders associated with the negotiation. Also, what exactly is the relationship you're trying to define? Is it 1:n? n:m? "An order *has many* negotiations" - so I assume the relationship should be `hasMany()` and not `belongsToMany()`. But what is the inverese relationship (negotiation -> order)? Can a negotiation be associated with several orders or just exclusively with one?

Comment: The database is populated and a negotiation is associated to just one order

Comment: Then the relationship should look like this: Order: `$this->hasMany('Negotiation')`, Negotiation: `$this->belongsTo('Order')`. You don't need a pivot table or anything, just make sure you have a column for the foreign order-key (`order_id`) in your Negotiation database-schema.

Comment: ok I changed it just like you say, I will accept this as an answer

Comment: Just debug it. Do it step by step, check what `dd(Negotiation::find($item->negotiation_id));` gives you, then check what `dd(Negotiation::find($item->negotiation_id)->order)` gives you and so on. If you described the relationship as I explained above, this should work just fine. Also, make sure to remove the second parameter from `$this->belongsToMany('Negotiation', 'orders_negotiations');`. Maybe you could also post the updated code and the schemas. Make sure the `order_id` fields are populated correctly on your negotiations table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the relationship:

- An Order *has many* Negotiations.
- A negotiation *belongs to* an
  order.

I think Laravel couldn't make it any more simpler to specify relationships, because it's almost exactly how you speak it:

```
class Order extends Eloquent 
{
    public function negotiations() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Negotiation');
    }
}

class Negotiation extends Eloquent 
{
    public function order() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order');
    }

}
```

And that's it. And, of course, with this kind of relationship you need to specify the  [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your tables / migrations:

```
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id');
    $table->string('number',64);
});

Schema::create('negotiations', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id');
    $table->integer('order_id'); //here it is
    $table->string('subject');
    // ... and so on
});
```

And that's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining a belongsToMany relationship, then you need to setup a pivot table.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships and look up the Many to Many relationship.

Unless it is a One to Many relationship do this.

```
public function negotiations() {
    return $this->hasMany('Negotiation', 'orders_negotiations');
}
```

Comment: umm I have a pivot table and in order I am defining `negotiations()` with `belongsToMany()`. However I made clear that is not my question. I am trying to retrieve the order from the negotiation. The opposite is done and working already.